# Is it possible to use iterators on 3D matrix in a template class?(c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

i'm trying to use iterators on a 3d matrix allocated dynamically.

```
   matrix = new T**[height];
        for(int i =0; i<height; i++){
            matrix[i] = new T*[col];
            for(int j =0; j<col; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = new T[row];


            }
        }
```

Is it possible to iterate over this matrix using iterators? Or is better to choose a different solution using iterators? (no vector solution)

If it's possible, how can I implement them?

Comment: You could use iterators with global  ::begin() and ::end() functions on your own defined type which wraps the array, or on a statically declared array, but not on dynamically allocated pointers. Is there any specific reason you want to use iterators here?

Comment: `new T**[height]` congratulations! You've become a [three-star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)! I.e. why are you not using a (wrapper around a)`std:vector`?

Comment: How do you want to iterate over it? Row-wise, column-wise, element-wise? Something else?

Comment: Can this allocation be shortened with `T (*matrix)[len_2][len_3] = new T[len_1][len_2][len_3]`? (though this would probably be simpler with an `std::vector`)

Comment: I'd recommend using a single 1D array and accessing the array with a 3D Index that gets calculated into offsets into the 1D Array.
It will make memory management way easier.
You can also make your class a template and use plain arrays with the template arguments which completely avoids dynamic allocation.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 This is only possible if both `len_2` and `len_3` are compile time constants (`len_1` does not need to be). Otherwise you rely on your compiler supporting VLA as extension – which I wouldn't recommend. With the lengths being dynamic, you can get a similar effect by allocating a one-dimensional array and doing the index calculations on your own (`[x][y][z]` gets `[(x * len_2 + y) * len_3 + z]`).

Comment: @Aconcagua yep, forgot about that issue :P

Answer (score 1):

Every pointer meets the criteria for an iterator, too. So you can iterate as follows:

```
for(T*** begin1 = matrix, end1 = matrix + height; begin1 != end1; ++begin1)
{
    for(T** begin2 = *begin1, end2 = *begin1 + col; begin2 != end2; ++begin2)
    {
        for(T* begin3 = *begin2, end3 = *begin2 + row; begin3 != end3; ++begin3)
        {
            begin3->doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

This works with standard library algorithms as well:

```
std::for_each
(
    matrix, matrix + height, [](T** t)
    {
        std::for_each
        (
            t, t + col, [](T* t)
            {
                std::for_each
                (
                    t, t + row, [](T& t)
                    {
                         t.doSomething();
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Untested code, if you find a bug, please fix it yourself.

You are likely better off with `std::vector`, though, this relieves you from all the manual memory management and additionally allows for much simpler construction:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> v
(
    height, std::vector<std::vector<T>>(col, std::vector<T>(row)
);
```

If you do not need jagged arrays for whatever reason, you will get more efficient code if you place all the values into a one-dimensional array/vector and do the index calculations on your own, then `[x][y][z]` corresponds to `[(x * col + y) * row + z]`.